# My crafting table will not make a fence?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm on survival and so far I've had no problems but as soon as I try and craft a fence I get nothing.

Comment: Have you checked if your recipe is right? Can you maybe provide a screenshot?

Comment: what version of minecraft are you playing in?

Answer (score 22):

The recipe for [fence](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence) changed in [Minecraft 1.8](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.8). The new recipe is as follows:

[image: New fence recipe]

Comment: It costs more? I want my third of a stick per fence back!

Comment: A small price to pay for fences in all wood types

Comment: @Johonn the other option would have been to introduce different types of sticks, but i supposed just changing the recipe to use wood planks was less work

Comment: @Memor-X not to mention I'd hate to have 6 different types of sticks... that would be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I figured it out(for at least version 1.8.3) it`s

plank stick plank 
plank stick plank

for fences &

stick plank stick 
stick plank stick

for fence gates

Confusing, yet true.

Comment: True, but also already answered above

Answer (score -1):

If you play in minecraft 1.8 
The crafting recipe change for fence, it become:

```
wood stick wood
Wood stick wood
```

So you can craft fences in your survival world

Comment: It is not wood but planks. You should consider arranging the ingredients in a tabular or (even better) provide a screenshot.

Answer (score -3):

The wood planks are on the side and the sticks are in the middle

Comment: Frank that does provide an answer to his question! I think you are just being a troll.